# UIGestureRecognizer and UIControlEventTouchUpInside work at the same time

Tags: ios, view, uigesturerecognizer, gestures

I am adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to my application to detect a double tap gesture.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
  tapgr.numberOfTaps = 2;
  tapgr.delegate = self;
  [_view addGestureRecognizer:tapgr];
  [tapgr release];
```

This is working fine unless I show a tooltip in my application. They are set up like this:

```
[_view.toolTipView addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Before the introduction of my gesture recognizer, these tooltips where clickable and reacted, now they aren't reacting anymore...

How can I make a gesture recognizer and a standard UIControlEventTouchUpInside-Setup work together?

Comment: See the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html under **Canceling and Delaying Touches**

Comment: sorry doesn't help... I already set cancelsTouchesInView to NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
 if (gestureRecognizer == tapgr) {
   return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]];
 }
 return YES;
}
```

This method prevents the GestureRecognizer from being fired when a UIControl (i.e. Button) is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the _view can respond single tap and Double tap together, you can try this

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap    = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
   UITapGestureRecognizer * doubleTap    = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

   [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

   //Add this code to disable double tap and only responds to single tap when user tap the _view just once time
   [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap]; 

   [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
   [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
   [singleTap release];
   [doubleTap release];
```

if you want to use TouchEvent try UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat

```
  [button addTarget:self actionselector(multipleTap:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];


  //Try to check wheather is doulbe tap or single tap.

  -(IBAction)multipleTap:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

     UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

     if (touch.tapCount == 2) {

     // do action.

     }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. I think you should choose another way to implement that.